# Flask dynamic page content

Tags: python

I am trying to write a dynamic page in Python with Flask on my pythonanywhere.com free hosting. I have the following code, hoping I could write to the `resp` variable to make my pages.

```
@app.route('/xdcc-search/search.html')
def search_app():
    try:
        with open('templates/xdcc-search/search.html', 'r') as dynamic:
            dynamic.read()
    except:
        pass
    dynamic.replace("<file>","MY_FILENAME.tar")
    resp = make_response(render_template(dynamic), 200)
    no_cache(resp)
    return resp
```

I get an error stating dynamic is referenced before assignment. Is there a way to edit the template after `render_template(filename)` retreives and assembles the page?

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
with open('templates/xdcc-search/search.html', 'r') as dynamic:
    dynamic.read()
```

...you are reading in the contents of the file, but you are throwing them away -- `read()` is a function that reads the contents of the file and returns them.

Fixing your code so that it actually does what you are trying to do gives this:

```
@app.route('/xdcc-search/search.html')
def search_app():
    try:
        with open('templates/xdcc-search/search.html', 'r') as dynamic:
            contents = dynamic.read()
    except:
        pass
    contents.replace("<file>","MY_FILENAME.tar")
    resp = make_response(render_template(contents), 200)
    no_cache(resp)
    return resp
```

...but that is still wrong; `render_template` takes as its parameter the name of the file that contains the template, not its contents.  So what you need to do to get this working would be to replace that `render_template` with `render_template_string`.

```
@app.route('/xdcc-search/search.html')
def search_app():
    try:
        with open('templates/xdcc-search/search.html', 'r') as dynamic:
            contents = dynamic.read()
    except:
        pass
    contents.replace("<file>","MY_FILENAME.tar")
    resp = make_response(render_template_string(contents), 200)
    no_cache(resp)
    return resp
```

But this is still not using Flask templates the way they are meant to be used.  The point of templates is that they should contain things in curly brackets to specify what changes should be made.  Replacing a static string inside one with an explicit call to `replace` bypasses that and does a more primitive version of the same thing.

What you *really* should be doing is changing your template so that instead of having `<file>` inside, it, it has `{{ file }}`, and then you can replace all of that messy view code with this:

```
@app.route('/xdcc-search/search.html')
def search_app():
    resp = make_response(render_template("xdcc-search/search.html", file="MY_FILENAME.tar"), 200)
    no_cache(resp)
    return resp
```

Finally, I'm not sure that you need that `no_cache`, as view functions are not cached by default.  Also, the default status code on a response is 200.  So probably all you need is this:

```
@app.route('/xdcc-search/search.html')
def search_app():
    return render_template("xdcc-search/search.html", file="MY_FILENAME.tar")
```